# How to split a fasta file into desired nucelotide length in R?

Tags: r, fasta

Being a complete beginner to a programming language and specially `R`, I am stuck at this problem since days

I have a random fasta file:

```
>header AAAATGGGGCTTTTACCCCGATA

My desired output is:

segment1 AAAAT
segment2 GGGGC
segment3 TTTTA
segment4 CCCCG
segment5 ATA
```

I need a small help in solving this. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
# Use the Biostrings package to parse fasta file and store long strings
# https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html 
require(Biostrings)

# Create test data
fileConn<-file("test.fa")
writeLines(c(
    ">header1",
    "AAAATGGGGC",
    "TTTTACCCCG",
    "ATA",
    ">header2",
    "ACGTACG"
), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

[image]

```
# Read fasta file
string_set <- readBStringSet("test.fa", format="fasta")
string_set
```

[image]

```
# Segment the first sequence
sequence = string_set[[1]]
sequence_length = length(sequence)
segment_length = 5

segment_count = ceiling(sequence_length/segment_length) # number of segments
segments <- lapply(1:segment_count, function(segment_id) {
    start_position <- (segment_id-1)*segment_length + 1
    end_position <- min(start_position + segment_length - 1, sequence_length)
    segment <- as.character(subseq(sequence,start_position,end_position))
    segment_name <- sprintf("Segment%s", segment_id)
    c(`Segment Name`=segment_name, `Segment`=segment)
})
segments <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, segments))
segments
```

[image]

Comment: If I want my output to be in the same way that you had already provided but in a siding window manner like `Segment1 AAAAT, Segment2 AAATG, Segment3 AATGG, Segment4 ATGGG, Segment5 TGGGG, Segment6 GGGGC, Segment7 GGGCT` and so on until last one, then what changes do I have to make in the source code? Would appreciate any help in this!